# how to install ruby-Tk on mac OSX catalina 10.15.4, ruby-2.6.3

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, tk-toolkit

Please could anyone help me with the best step by step instruction to install ruby-Tk on mac OSX catalina 10.15.4 running ruby-2.6.3. doing

```
gem install tk
```

gives me this error. "Can't find "tk.h". Can't find proper Tcl/Tk libraries. So, can't make tcltklib.so which is required by Ruby/Tk." Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below guide assumes you have Xcode already installed. If not install it first from the apple app store.

1) Install ActiveTcl for macOS from https://www.activestate.com
under applications/utilities, there will be a new app wish.app. run this app and if you get the wish console to open, then, it installed ok

2) Using your command line do the following

```
brew install ruby #this will install latest version of ruby
gem install tk
```

3) then add other ruby gems that you need for your development environment.

Comment: Only version 8.5 of ActiveTcl will work fully, because no version of Ruby supports Tcl version 8.6.

Comment: If I open the URL you mention I get a glossy company page and no indication where to download ActiveTcl. gem install tk fails with "Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options." LOL. Checked the log and found sourcecode snippets. Also no info on what configuration options I might be needing.